# How to create disordered arrays with differently sized cubes

Tags: objects, particles

I am struggling a little bit with this one. I came back to blender after 3 or 4 months without almost ouching it, and I justdon't know if I am super rusty or getting dumber.

I am trying to create some concept for a scientif grant. On the left image I want to show an array of cubes, perfectly packed. On the right image, I want to do the same, but introducing samll amounts of cubes that are 1.8x times bigger than the original ones. My idea is that by the introduction of the bigger cubes, disorder will spontaneously appear in the array, giving rise to empty spaces due to the missmatch in sizes between the cubes (see reference image).

I know how to create the ordered array in blender by using the geometry nodes and also particle systems. However, creating the disordered one is being really challenging. I have tried Geo nodes, instancing points on a plane with poisson disk distribution and space contraints but the packing of my cubes is either really poor (large spaces between them) or the cubes clip each other which I would like to avoid.

Is there any way to do this? Lately, I have been resorting on using a brick texture instead of particle systems or geo nodes, but it quite bad.[image: Order/disorder]

Thanks!